# Как устроен массива типа char?

Tags: c++, массивы, строки, указатели

Когда я создаю `char name[] = "John"` и пытаюсь разыменовать `*name` то получаю `J`. Это значит name сам по себе это адрес? Если да, то адрес чего? Насколько я знаю, если оператор `<<` видит тип `char *`, то вместо адреса он выводит С-строку. Поэтому ссылаюсь на то, что выводит мне `<<` , не зная тонкостей. Можно ли обьяснение как устроен массив типа `char`

Answer (score 6):

Как и любой другой массив - подряд в памяти расположены элементы типа `char`. Имя массива выступает неизменяемым указателем (вы не можете заставить ваше `name` указывать на другой массив) на первый элемент массива.

Поэтому `*name` означает сам первый элемент массива с типом `char`.

Ну, а в С++ организовано так, что `cout` выполняет вывод, основываясь на типе выводимого, и, видя `char*`, он выводит переданное как строку в стиле С (которая представляет собой массив символов; для указания завершения *строки* (не самого массива - в массиве в 1000 элементов может располагаться слово из 3 букв) используется не выводимый нулевой символ (не `'0'`, а именно `0` (ну, или `'\0'` - как вам удобнее записывать)).

Comment: То есть пытаясь вывести мой `name` (который является указателем на адрес первого элемента массива `name`?) через `<<` , оператор вывода ссылаясь на `name` (который указатель на адрес первого элемента?) будет выводить все адреса типа `char` пока не встретит нуль-терминатор? Все адреса следующие после адреса первого элемента `name`

Comment: Не адреса, а символы, следующие за тем, на который указывает переданный указатель. *Примерно* `cout << name` можно рассматривать как `char* tmp = name; while(*tmp) cout << *tmp++;`